# File naming convention and allowed characters between different OS

Tags: php, file, file-io, fopen

I'm wring a piece of code in PHP for saving email attachments. **Can i assume that this will never fail because different allowed characters between OS?**

```
foreach($message->attachments as $a)
{
   // Make dir if not exists
   $dir = __DIR__ . "/saved/$uid"; // Message id
   if (!file_exists($dir)) mkdir($dir) or die("Cannot create: $dir");

   // Save the attachment using original!!! filename as found in email
   $fp = fopen($dir . '/' . $a->filename, 'w+');
   fwrite($fp, $a->data);
   fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: @rootatwc yep a little error, see my edits, but the point of the question is about filename of the attachment.

Comment: Is there an email ID or unique string that you can make use?

Comment: @ajreal not an ID for every attachment, only the message ID that should be unique for a given message for a given mailbox.

Comment: ah i see.just dont keep the original name,give it a new random name and save headaches for security implications too.

Comment: Yup, you should give the attachments name like $email_id-1, $email_id-2, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is good practice to replace certain characters that may occur in filenames on windows.

Unix can handle almost any character in a file name (but not "/" and 0x00 [the null Character]), but to prevent encoding problems and difficulties on downloading a file I would suggest to replace anything that does not match
`/[A-Za-Z0-9_-\.]/g`, which satisfies the POSIX fully portable filename format.

so a `preg_replace("/[^A-Za-Z0-9_-\.]/g","_",$filename);` will do a good job.

a more generous approach would be to replace only `|\?*<":>+[]\x00/` which leaves special language characters like öäü untouched and is compatible with FAT32, NTFS, any Unix and Mac OS X.

in that case use `preg_replace("/[\|\\\?\*<\":>\+\[\]\/]\x00/g","_",$filename);`

Answer (score 2):

You should never use a name that you have no control over, it can contain all sorts of characters, like `../../..`.

You can use a function like [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to clean it up and a constant like `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to separate directories.

Personally I would rename the file but you can also filter the variables before using them.

Comment: This is not an answer but a best practice, thanks for the tip about `basename`, i will use it along with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. The question remains: `$a->filename` can contain not allowed characters? +1 for the tip.

Comment: @Gremo How's that not an answer? If your filename contains `../../` at the start, your operation will fail (I hope for you...) due to insufficient rights.

Comment: @Gremo Yes, that's why I suggested filtering if you don't want to rename it :-)

Answer (score 0):

NO, you should assume that this will have a high probability of failing.  for 2 reasons:

1. what if 2 emails have files named the same (selfie.jpg, for example)?
2. what if filename contains unacceptable characters?

you should use an internal naming convention (user+datetime+sequential, for example) and save names in a MySQL table with at least 3 fields:

1. Id - Autonumbered
2. filename - as saved by your php
3. original name - as in the original email
4. optional username - or usercode or email address of whomever sent email
5. optional datetime stamp

save the original filename as a VARCHAR and you will be able to keep track of original name and even show it, search for it, etc.